# MyPy error: "object" has no attribute "get"

Tags: python, mypy

I am converting PyArrow types to their json-schema.org equivalent.  The code works, all unit tests pass but MyPy gives  the error

```
error: "object" has no attribute "get"
```

I have a dictionary as follows

```
from pyarrow import bool_, date32, float64, int64, string

DATATYPE_MAPPING = {
    string(): {"json_type": "string", "example_value": "Words"},
    bool_(): {"json_type": "bool", "example_value": True},
    int64(): {"json_type": "integer", "example_value": 32},
    float64(): {"json_type": "number", "example_value": 3.14},
    date32(): {
        "json_type": "string",
        "example_value": "2020-02-01",
        "format": "date",
    },
}
```

This is used to translate data types from the results of PyArrow.csv.read_csv as follows

```
        arrow_reader = csv.read_csv(
            self.input_file,
            read_options=csv_read_options,
            parse_options=csv_parse_options,
        )

        self.column_headers = arrow_reader.column_names

        # Build the list converting PyArrow types to json-schema.org types
        data_type_list = [
            DATATYPE_MAPPING[datatype].get("example_value", "string")
            for datatype in arrow_reader.schema.types
        ]
```

MyPy does not understand that a DATATYPE_MAPPING[datatype] is a dictionary.
How can I get instruct it that it is a dictionary?
If not, can I get MyPy to ignore this problem?

Comment: hint `DATATYPE_MAPPING : dict[<some pyarrow type>, dict[str, object]]`. You could also use `TypedDict` if you want more control (which you may need to set the default to `"string"`), since some of your values are numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joel for this.

```
from pyarrow import DataType, bool_, date32, float64, int64, string

DATATYPE_MAPPING: dict[DataType, dict[str, object]] = {
    string(): {"json_type": "string", "example_value": "Words"},
    bool_(): {"json_type": "bool", "example_value": True},
    int64(): {"json_type": "integer", "example_value": 32},
    float64(): {"json_type": "number", "example_value": 3.14},
    date32(): {
        "json_type": "string",
        "example_value": "2020-02-01",
        "format": "date",
    },
}
```